# Jyotisha - Relation between Pancha Mahabhuta and Rashi

Tags: astrology, panchabhoota, rashi

What is the relationship between [Pancha Mahabhuta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancha_Bhoota) and Rashi in Jyotisha?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the material world is made up of five great elements/PanchaMahabhuta, everything is associated it with. Similarly in Jyotish the 12 constellation are also related with it. It shows which constellation/Rashi is characterized by which Tatwa.

According to classification by **Brihat Parashar Horashastra  from 4.6-4.24:**

> (1) Ar(Mesha), Le(Simha) and Sg(Dhanu) are called **agni rasis** or fiery rasis.
>
> (2) Ta(Vrisha), Vi(Kanya) and Cp(Makara) are called **bhoo rasis** or earthy rasis.
>
> (3) Ge(Mithun), Li(Tula) and Aq(Kumbha) are called **vaayu rasis** or airy rasis.
>
> (4) Cn(Karkat), Sc(Vrischik) and Pi(Meen) are called **jala rasis** or watery rasis.
>
> (5) The 5th element of aakaasa or ether is present in every rasi.

### Significance in Jyotish:

This classification of Rashi based on the Panchatatwa is of great significance in Jyotish. We can find the nature of person by studying the Tatwas and their potencies in a birth chart.

> For example, the 5th house in one’s chart shows one’s emotional nature. The 5th house in a fiery sign may show a normally angry, aggressive or determined person. The 5th house in an earthy sign may show a 
>   balanced, logical and stable person. The 5th house in an airy sign may show someone with unstable and wandering emotions. The 5th house in a watery sign may show one with an imaginative and creative mind.

Comment: Nice, I have seen people associating Sc with fire for some reason. Also, Kumbha reminds me of water lol

Comment: I didn't know that space is associated with all. Btw, do you have an online version of the BPHS?

Comment: Also, nice example on how to relate a house with an element. Very insightful.

Comment: @AmitSaxena for kumbha at 4.21  "It resorts to deep water and is airy." Yes Sc reminds of fire because we remember angry anf fierce nature of scorpin. But there is another interesting thing to observe. Have you observed it...?   They are in order and rotating.... ie. Mesh fire, Vrish earth, Mithun air, Karkat water.. again Simha fire, Kanya earth.... ie. They are rotating in the order of Ar, Ta, Ge, Cn, Le, Vi, Li, Sc, Sg, Cp, Aq, Pi...... I have pdf version of BPHS donot know about online versions....

Comment: Any idea, why is it saying deep water?